# Badged Buttons from Non-SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Does anyone have any tricks on how to use the badged buttons feature of addon-sdk from non-sdk addons? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#Badged_buttons

If no tricks my thinking was to use maybe override xbl and/or override `display='xul:button'` from techniques listed here: [To anonymous element add pseudo element and cursor style and event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396380/to-anonymous-element-add-pseudo-element-and-cursor-style-and-event-listeners)

Comment: I stumbled on a comment (in bugzilla I think) which indicated that Mozilla are planning to allow an easy way to import any SDK feature into a non-SDK addon. Afraid I can't remember the timing of their plan or exactly where I read it but thought you might be interested even if it's not a solution right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always look at the SDK source code. Here's the [pertinent line](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/ui/button/view.js#L140)

```
node.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional badged-button');
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I did. I'm in the process of looking into the rules of that styling/binding. Because that class probably didn't exist for Firefox 29. I think badging came out later right?

Comment: [FF 36, unfortunately](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#Badged_buttons)

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! That validates my effort to make my own bindings (well just steal them from FF36+)